# What are some good questions to ask in a job interview to determine if potential employees have IT skills?

Tags: interviewing

I conduct job interviews a lot.  I do this for a company that, among other things, requires a certain amount of IT knowledge.  They're not looking for "computer experts" but they do look for "computer intuition" - people who know their way around a Windows PC computer generally, i.e what a URL does, how to move and minimise windows, how to use Windows File Explorer, how to identify if an email might be a phishing attempt - basic stuff like that, nothing that any 13 year old today doesn't know how to do.  I'm running into two problems when trying to determine which staff should be hired:

1. Often people who have a long list of computer aptitudes and software packages on their resume still don't have raw "computer know-how".  If a previous employer has babysat then through every step of using the 10% of MS Office that they needed for their old role, then having "MS Office proficiency" on their resume, although true, doesn't really indicate anything.
2. People occasionally lie.  "Do you have IT skills?"  "Yes."  And then they sit down in front of a computer and need help dragging a window.

My idea to solve this issue is to format part of the job interview like a quiz.  What I'm looking for is some good questions that I can ask people during an interview, that will confirm their level of "general" IT knowledge.  Something like "what is a URL?" might be one, but there may be other/better ones.  Some things that don't sound silly to ask, that someone with good computer common-sense will instantly be able to answer, but someone who has been babysat through their whole life when it comes to computers, will struggle with.

Comment: "how to set up printing" - this is often the hardest task of all on a PC...

Comment: @Philip Kendall sorry but you have failed the interview

Comment: Can you add why your boss would block attempts to give a practical test, and what other things they might block? It gives us a bit more clarity on what your solution space is.

Comment: @KimJiwoo, you seem not to understand that it's one thing to plug the printer and connect it to your private computer and another to connect to an office printer, which frequently requires jumping through some hoops.

Comment: "IT skills" is so vague that it esentially means "do you do the computer things?"

Comment: @BigMadAndy I removed the printer example, it's probably a poorer example of what I'm talking about and it was distracting a lot of people.

Comment: @Flater I think "generic IT savvy" is a fairly easily understood thing.  Call it "computer intuition".  Some people, you sit them in front of a computer and they "get it".  GIve them a new program to learn that they've never seen before and they pick it up quickly, because they understand what programs look like and how they operate generally speaking.  That's someone who has what we're looking for.  Other people who don't "get it" are the type who might take an "adult computer course" that teaches them what an icon is and how you have to double click to open it etc.  Call it what you want.

Comment: @Erik interviews, we do a lot of them and the focus is on efficiently getting through them, they're a big time sink for myself and those in management.  Anything that significantly lengthens or complicates the interview process is going to get vetoed.  However just adding a few effective questions will get over the line with the boss.

Comment: It is hard to me to believe that software people cannot minimize windows. Nor would I call a software engineer lying if they say they have IT skills. For this question, I would not think about minimizing windows.

Comment: If you want to gauge IT skills, get an IT expert to do it.... just ask them to describe how to do simple things on a windows pc. Or describe some pc issue they solved in the past. With experience you can gauge how competent they are pretty easily. If you don't have the knowledge and experience yourself though, you have no place trying to gauge others in such a short time. I'm a network engineer so could dismantle and fix your printer, install it, network it and even change the toner.... and have troubleshot every sort of office software available. Someone like me should be asking the questions

Answer (score 11):

Rather than asking questions, why not just sit them down in front of a computer<sup>1</sup> and ask them to do some of these basic tasks? You'll very rapidly get an idea as to their skill level.

<sup>1. In this COVID age, substitute "watch them on a screen share".</sup>

Comment: Would if I could but not an option sadly.  Boss would veto it.

Comment: Since this is something you know will make you better at your job, are you required to submit it to your boss for approval?

Comment: Trust me - don't even go there.  If a practical test was an option I wouldn't even be asking the original question here.  Has already been ruled out.

Comment: In this COVID age, the worst offenders will already be snuffed out by not figuring out how to screen share.

Comment: @Flater if they have technical problems or can't join the interview in time we nix the interview, as these are done remotely due to COVID.  I like your idea about the screen share, getting them to share a screen is clever as we currently don't ask for this, only for them to join the interview.

Comment: @Flater - What about those of who would refuse to screen share for privacy reasons?  Most of the time I help individuals do their job, a job their company was paid hundreds of thousands of dolllars to perform, since I know more about the individual systems then they do

Comment: @Donald Then you don't get the job. If you're being asked to demonstrate that you're competent at (say) Excel, just share the Excel window. I really can't see the "privacy concerns" there.

Comment: @Donald: Why are you asking me? I didn't bring up the suggestion of screen sharing, I just commented on the fact that the sharing itself requires some computer literacy.

Answer (score 3):

Seeing as you've already ruled out putting them in front of a computer to test their skills....

One thing I used to do was to conduct a mock phone support issue.  You can play the part of a user who needs help and have your interviewee play the part of the support person.  You can let them use whatever they need to get the job done, but the only thing they can do is just talk to you.  Not only don't you need sign off from your boss, but in a COVID age, it's remote-interview friendly as well

Answer (score 2):

The main question in your case shouldn't be how you determine candidates' IT skills.

The main question here should be what IT skills exactly you need and why.

"IT skills" is a huge area. Personally, I'm very good in some IT areas, including programming skills. But if my laptop stops recognizing headsets I run to the helpdesk. Yes, I could try solving that myself, but it would be inefficient and I don't have time for that. Similarly with setting up printers in the office. Why should I waste my time for that, time I could spend creating value for my organization with my main skills? My hour of work is much, much more expensive than 30 minutes of work of our helpdesk.

The ability to do something is one thing, the willingness to do it another.

So it's really important that you define what you are precisely looking for and **talk about it openly** with the candidate. If you have bad processes for workplace infrastructure which make users run into problems constantly - I once worked at such an employer - then it's important for the candidates to know it, since it can diminish job satisfaction quite a bit.

If you already know what you need, checking it is easy. **Ask "what would you do" questions** and ask candidates to be more specific if they are giving you generic answers. Then you see whether the answers are more "I would first check the settings and then google it if needed" or more of "I would ask helpdesk" in type.

But it's important for you to know why you need it.

Also, you have to know that some of your "basic competencies" aren't basic at all. At my company the fail rate of a phishing test is currently at around 30% despite all the courses, memos, warnings. So, according to you, one third of our office employees, 90% of which have tertiary education, don't have the skills of "any 13 year old today".

Answer (score 1):

**You are basically looking for troubleshooting skill/and/or tech savvy.**

"Computer know-how" is basically just the ability to figure out a fairly complex system with many ways to the end goal. Either that or the curiosity to Google it as well as the skill to phrase it correctly.

I’m a software engineer, so I hope I meet your standard of technical. I couldn’t tell you off hand how to set up a printer. I could do one of two things:

1. Use the proper terminology for the task. I would know to start with the “installation wizard.”  If that did not work, I would know to do a Google search with the “model number” of the printer. I would know that an IP address mismatch might cause a printer to appear offline.  It may not be a useful explanation of how to install a printer, but it would be abundantly clear that I have installed one before.
2. Demonstrate enough curiosity that if you were a printer generating error messages, I would be able to ask detailed questions about why you are not working. You could simply start the question sequence with “pretend I am a printer that needs to be installed. What do you do? What questions would you ask me?” I assume you know enough about printers to pretend to be one to some standard.

Either approach should get you people who are at least reasonably skilled with technology.

I would support a practical test too, but you already stated you cannot do that.

Comment: I just want to add an asterisk to the "proper terminology" point. People who learn by themselves, without communicating with others, often don't know the names of concepts while they do know the concepts themselves. Anecdotally, during an interview I was asked about string immutability and could not explain it. But the interviewer then asked me why string+string is a bad idea, and I explained the issues with concatenation down to the memory allocation consequences. I just didn't know that "immutable" was its name. If the interviewer judged me solely by my terminology, I would've failed.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you can't put them in front of an actual computer for a practical test, perhaps you could create a few screenshots of situations that might come up in your job that would require this little bit of IT-skill, and present them to your interviewee and ask them what they would do.

This doesn't require the technology, but might still help. Present a screenshot from a browser with some kind of issue, and then ask the interviewee "What's wrong in this image?" and if they identify the problem, ask them "What would you do in this situation?" might give you a lot of insight.

A very simple example might be a browser showing a 404 with a url visible that clearly has a typo in it. Likewise, a program complaining about not having an internet connection, or a network screen with no other visible computers, while having the "ethernet cable unplugged" icon visible in the status bar.